# Getting individual class and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a working keyboard without plugins on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/dM3Gs/1/). I have each button as an individual element, but in order for my `$().append()` function to work, I need to get the class *and* value of the button clicked in a short amount of code. The only way I can think of doing this is by creating a variable for each button, and making a `$().click()` function for each button.

HTML:

```
<button class='q'>Q</button><button class='w'>W</button><button class='e'>E</button>        <button class='r'>R</button><button class='t'>T</button><button class='y'>Y</button><button class='u'>U</button><button class='i'>I</button><button class='o'>O</button><button class='p'>P</button><br />
<button style='margin-left: 23px;' class='a'>A</button><button class='s'>S</button><button class='d'>D</button><button class='f'>F</button><button class='g'>G</button><button class='h'>H</button><button class='j'>J</button><button class='k'>K</button><button class='l'>L</button><br />
<button style='margin-left: 70px;' class='z'>Z</button><button class='x'>X</button><button class='c'>C</button><button class='v'>V</button><button class='b'>B</button><button class='n'>N</button><button class='m'>M</button>
<br />
<br />
<h1></h1>
```

CSS:

```
body: {
  text-align: center
}
button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid #6699ff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #6699ff;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  margin: 3px;
}
button:hover {
  border: 2px solid #5c8ae6;
  color: #5c8ae6
}
button:active{
  border: 2px solid #5c8ae6;
  background: #5c8ae6;
  color: white;
}
button:focus {
  outline: 0
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the letter of each button...

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('button').click(function() {
          //alert($(this).html());
          $('h1').append(this.textContent);
     });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GK595/1)**

Comment: If you look at the fiddle, you can obviously see the letters in the buttons. I want to be able to get the letter, and do something with it.

Comment: also, when i try to replace the alert with the `$().append()`, it appends the entire button, not the letter

Comment: You can get the letter with `$('button').html()`

Comment: @imbondbaby you are welcome and that is a correct answer for me. That has to be it.

Comment: does someone now know how to add the space?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the buttons in a div

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class='q'>Q</button><button class='w'>W</button><button class='e'>E</button><button class='r'>R</button><button class='t'>T</button><button class='y'>Y</button><button class='u'>U</button><button class='i'>I</button><button class='o'>O</button><button class='p'>P</button><br />
    <button style='margin-left: 23px;' class='a'>A</button><button class='s'>S</button><button class='d'>D</button><button class='f'>F</button><button class='g'>G</button><button class='h'>H</button><button class='j'>J</button><button class='k'>K</button><button class='l'>L</button><br /><button style='margin-left: 70px;' class='z'>Z</button><button class='x'>X</button><button class='c'>C</button><button class='v'>V</button><button class='b'>B</button><button class='n'>N</button><button class='m'>M</button>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<h1></h1>
<div class="output"></div>
```

and then use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(function(){
    $(".buttons").on("click", "button", function(e){
        $(".output").append(this.className);
        // Or text()
        // $(".output").append($(this).text());
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dM3Gs/3/)